# Beamer Ilmenau theme: navigation switching between sections

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I'm using the beamer Ilmenau theme. I have two sections (pros and cons) that need to be presented simultaneously during the presentation. Currently the navigation shows the bullets for each subsection (frames) of pros and cons separately. I would prefer if there was a way to switch between the two sections, for instance, start with first dot in the pros section and then jump to the first dot in the cons section and so on with this type of flow. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame} 

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Welcome}
So this is where we start..
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Electric Vehicles}\vspace{4pt}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Pros}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Really good}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Awesome to say the least}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{No doubt}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{One word: Epic}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\section{Cons}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Privacy issues}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Danger!}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Keep away}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Are you serious?}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{The verdict...}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! You could always rearrange the slides in the finished pdf - either using tex or some other tools.

Comment: If the majority of your frames is top aligned, maybe its easier to write `\documentclass[t]{beamer}`

Comment: Are you aware of "display priority", i.e. `\item<2>` things? You can basically freely choose how many build-up pages for a complete frame you get and what lands on which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nameref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]\label{toc}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame} 

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}[t]\label{welcome}
\frametitle{Welcome}
So this is where we start..
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,label={Vehicles}]
\frametitle{Electric Vehicles}\vspace{4pt}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Pros}
\subsection{Pros 1}
\begin{frame}[t,label={Pros1}]
\frametitle{Really good}\vspace{4pt} 

\begin{center}
\hyperlink{Cons1}{\beamerbutton{Cons}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Pros 2}
\begin{frame}[t,label={Pros2}]
\frametitle{Awesome to say the least}\vspace{4pt}

\begin{center}
\hyperlink{Cons2}{\beamerbutton{Cons}}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Pros 3}
\begin{frame}[t,label={Pros3}]
\frametitle{No doubt}\vspace{4pt}

\begin{center}
\hyperlink{Cons3}{\beamerbutton{Cons}}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Pros 4}

\begin{frame}[t,label={Pros4}]
\frametitle{One word: Epic}\vspace{4pt}

\begin{center}
\hyperlink{Cons4}{\beamerbutton{Cons}}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}

\section{Cons}
\subsection{Cons 1}
\begin{frame}[t,label={Cons1}]
\frametitle{Privacy issues}\vspace{4pt}

\begin{center}
\hyperlink{Pros2}{\beamerbutton{Pros}}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Cons 2}
\begin{frame}[t]\label{Cons2}
\frametitle{Danger!}\vspace{4pt}

\begin{center}
\hyperlink{Pros3}{\beamerbutton{Pros}}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Cons 3}
\begin{frame}[t]\label{Cons3}
\frametitle{Keep away}\vspace{4pt}

\begin{center}
\hyperlink{Pros4}{\beamerbutton{Pros}}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Cons 4}

\begin{frame}[t]\label{Cons4}
\frametitle{Are you serious?}\vspace{4pt}

\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{The verdict...}\vspace{4pt}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP uses the standard theme `Ilmenau` included with the package, but mistyped the name with a lower-case `i`. This theme has little "navigation dots" called mini frames in the headline, and he wants the active slide marker to jump back and forth between the pros and cons sections.

Comment: You don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer.

Comment: OP here.. Thanks a lot for your efforts. Not exactly what I had in mind though. I was looking for sth like a jump from Pros1 to Cons1 then again from Pros2 to Cons2 and so on..

Comment: Just fixed... The idea was already the same... the numbers are different

Comment: Works great now!! just a remark: the hyperlink is too obvious, is there a way around to make it look more pro? thanks :)

Comment: You can put a text or a picture or whatever instead of the `beamerbutton` command but I think the picture has some prob;ems with XeLaTeX if you want to use it too and I haven't check with latex... Just play around to find your own style